# How to avoid empty line and comment line when substitute string?

Tags: substitute

Want to convert

```
 //comment  
 abc_def      ...

 thank_you123 ...
```

to

```
 //comment       
 .abc_def ( abc_def ),   

 .thank_you123 ( thank_you123 ),
```

with single substitute command.
Need to avoid both empty lines and comment lines.
Comment line starts with `//`.
`abc_def` can be a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and `_`.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you:

`:%s#\(//.*\)\@<![a-zA-Z0-9_]\+#.& ( & ),#g`

Explanation:

`:%s/[a-zA-Z0-9_]\+/.& ( & ),/`

Replaces `abc_def` by `.abc_def( abc_def ),`

The `g` flag make sure the replacement is done multiple times in the line if necessary.

The `\(\/\/.*\)\@<!` make the replacement only if the string is not preceded by `//`.

To avoid the ugly `\/\/` we can use `#` instead of the standard `/` in the substitute command.

An alternative using very magic is:

`:%s#\v(//.*)@<![a-zA-Z0-9_]+#.& ( & ),#g`

Comment: I'm not sure the `_def` in the pattern is correct (see the second example)

Comment: I miss understood the demand that was formulated slightly differently :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `:g` command:

```
:v#^\s*//#s/\w\+/.&( & ),/g
```

where `:v` will execute the following command on all lines **not** matching the pattern. So in this case, this will execute the `:s` command on all non-comment lines.

Comment: Hi Christian, sorry for my previous message. I was wrong about the comment type. But I believe your solution don't replace line like ``abc_def // my comment``.

Comment: yes that is true, but could be easily fixed by using: `:v#^\s*//#s...` :)

Comment: But this one convert the instance in the comment ``abc_def // hij_def`` devient ``.abc_def( abd_def ), // .hij_def( hij_def ),`` .

Comment: yes, but that was not asked :)